# Корректная работа кнопки назад

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как в этом скрипте, который подгружает новости сделать, чтоб корректно работала кнопка назад, сейчас кидает в самый низ сайта

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $('body').on('click','#nav-load a',function(){
  var urlNext = $(this).attr('href');
  var scrollNext = $(this).offset().top - 200;
        if (urlNext !== undefined) {
   $.ajax({
    url: urlNext,
    beforeSend: function() {
     ShowLoading('');
    },    
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#bottom-nav').remove();
                    $('#dle-content').append($('#dle-content', data).html());
                    $('#dle-content').after($('#bottom-nav'));
     window.history.pushState("", "", urlNext);
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollNext}, 800); 
     HideLoading('');
                },
      error: function() {    
     HideLoading('');
     alert('что-то пошло не так');
      }
   });
  };
  return false;
 });
 
});
```